# Bootstrap Modal and Datatables.net

Tags: datatables, bootstrap-modal

I am displaying a bootstrap modal dialog from within a datatables event handler that is defined like this:

```js
   dt_table.on('click', 'tr', function(e) {
        //console.log('row clicked');
        if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        }
        else {
            //check to see if user has any pending changes
            var saveButton = document.getElementById('saveBtn');
            if (saveButton && !saveButton.disabled) {
                //for now if save button is enabled ask user if they're sure they don't want to save pending changes first
                var options = {
                  'backdrop' : 'static',  //prevents clicking outside the model to dismiss dialog
                }
                $('#pendingChanges').modal(options);
                var save_pending_changes = $('#save_pending_changes').val();
                console.log(save_pending_changes);
                if (save_pending_changes) {
//                    console.log(e);
                    //e.preventDefault();
                    return;
                }
            }

            console.log('about to execute default behavior');

            //first unselect any other selected row
            dt_table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');

            //then select row of interest
            $(this).addClass('selected');

            var rowIndices = dt_table.row('.selected')[0];
            selectedRowIndex = rowIndices[0];

            //set hidden param
            $('#selectedRowIndex').val(selectedRowIndex);

            var row = dt_table.rows(rowIndices);

            if (row.data().length == 0) {
                //e.preventDefault();
                return;
            }
            var id = row.data()[0]['id'];
            var url = '/report/' + id + '/';
            //window.location = url;
            $('#notes_display').load(url +  ' #notes_display');
        }
    });
```

The issue I'm running into is that the entire event handler executes before the modal is dismissed. It's behaving as if the modal is running in it's own thread.  How can I fix this?

My modal is defined as

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="pendingChanges" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="pendingChangesLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title" id="pendingChangesLabel">You have unsaved changes</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>
            <strong>Are you sure you want to leave?</strong>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="saveChanges(true)">No</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="saveChanges(false)">Yes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sample of the logic would have been helpful :) But guess I understand the problem. I will recommend you split the workflow up in promises :

```js
//determine if modal should displayed
function determine(tr) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    //dont know the logic here 
    resolve(true / false)
  })
}

//show modal and return caption of the clicked button
function showModal() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    $('#pendingChanges button').one('click', function(e) {
      resolve(e.currentTarget.innerText)
    })
    $('#pendingChanges').modal({
      backdrop: 'static',
      keyboard: false
    })    
  })
}

dt_table.on('click', 'tr', function(e) {
  determine(this).then(function(result) {
    if (result) {
      showModal().then(function(button) {
        console.log(button) //Yes or No
      })
    }
  })
})
```

Not tested but should be OK.

1. `determine()` if the modal should be shown based on the `<tr>`
2. Call `showModal()` which is only resolved when a button is clicked
3. You get either `Yes` or `No`

Comment: That looks promising (no pun intended), but I haven't quite got it working yet.  I'll keep working on it, in the meantime I've included the rest of my code above.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [davidkonrad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1407478/davidkonrad) I solved my issue.  Here's the working code.

```html
<input type="hidden" name="save_pending_changes" id="save_pending_changes" value="false"/>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="pendingChanges" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="pendingChangesLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title" id="pendingChangesLabel">You have unsaved changes</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>
            <strong>Are you sure you want to leave?</strong>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="saveChanges(true)">No</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="saveChanges(false)">Yes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
function saveChanges(save) {
    $('#save_pending_changes').val(save);
}

dt_table.on('click', 'tr', function(e) {
    var oldRow = getCurrentRow();
    determine(this).then(function(result) {
        var enabled = result['enabled'];
        var tr = result['tr'];
        if (enabled) {
            showModal().then(function(save) {
                if (save == 'true') {
                    setSelection(oldRow);
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    select(tr);
                }
            })
        }
        else {
            select(tr);
        }
    })
})

//determine if modal should displayed
function determine(tr) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        //check to see if user has any pending changes
        var saveButton = document.getElementById('saveBtn');
        var enabled = false;
        if (saveButton) {
            enabled = !saveButton.disabled;
        }
        var result = {};
        result['enabled'] = enabled;
        result['tr'] = tr;
        resolve(result);
    })
}

//show modal and return caption of the clicked button
function showModal() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        $('#pendingChanges button').one('click', function(e) {
            var save_pending_changes = $('#save_pending_changes').val();
            resolve(save_pending_changes);
        })
        $('#pendingChanges').modal({
            backdrop: 'static',
            keyboard: false
        })
    })
}

function getCurrentRow() {
    return (dt_table.$('tr.selected'));
}

function setSelection(row) {
    //first unselect any other selected row
    dt_table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');

    //then select row
    row.addClass('selected');
}

function select(tr) {
    //first unselect any other selected row
    dt_table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');

    //then select row of interest
    $(tr).addClass('selected');

    var rowIndices = dt_table.row('.selected')[0];
    selectedRowIndex = rowIndices[0];

    //set hidden param
    $('#selectedRowIndex').val(selectedRowIndex);

    var row = dt_table.rows(rowIndices);

    if (row.data().length == 0) {
        //e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
    var id = row.data()[0]['id'];
    var url = '/report/' + id + '/';
    //window.location = url;
    $('#notes_display').load(url +  ' #notes_display');

}
```